# scan data not published after running depthimage_to_laserscan

Tags: nvidia, realsense-camera, jetson, depthimage-to-laserscan, rostopic-echo

Camera : Intel realsense 435D
Computing device : NVIDIA JETSON ORIN
currently im converting depthimage to laserscan .I'm providing the package(depthimage_to_laserscan) with the topics /camera_info and /depth_image .I can see that /scan topic is published but there is no message inside the topic,i confirm my claim because when i try to "rostopic echo /scan " the code goes to segmentation fault.

note: interestingly the same code works fine in my PC .